# Issue in deploying Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, angular6

I have upgraded my Angular 4 project to Angular 6. It is running successfully on local. After deployment to systest, when i am accessing the home url , it is throwing me the following error:

[image]

Following is my routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'Logout', component: LogoutComponent },
];
```

I've created the build by the following command:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /<projectname>/<projectname>.UI/
```

following is my config file:

```html
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  
   <staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
        <caching>

        </caching>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: remove slash from redirectTo: '/Home' into redirectTo: 'Home'.

And check whether it helps?

Comment: @PandiyanCool no luck.

Comment: try { path: '**', redirectTo: 'Home' } as last row

Comment: try `console.log('location: ', window.location.href);`. You will have better idea if you need the _/pathName_ or _pathName_